# Is there a solution to cast serries to a single data in pine editor?

Tags: pine-script

I am writing a simple pine script to show me the yesterday and last week min and max and few other parameters.
The problem is that the the output of High and Low functions are series but the hline functions with a single float value! I have already tried to utilize the plot function. The main problem in this case is that it shows the min and max for all previous weeks, not only the last week. The older data are not required in my strategy.

https://www.tradingview.com/x/kBXx404J/

```
`// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © hesam_kaf

//@version=4
study("Daily and Weekly Resistances", shorttitle="Prev Wk H-L", overlay=true)
prevwkH = input(true, title="Show previous week high?")
prevwkL = input(true, title="show previous week low?")
prevwkM = input(true, title="show previous week middle?")
prevwkMH = input(true, title="show previous week middle high?")
prevwkML = input(true, title="show previous week middle low?")
prevdH = input(true, title="show previous day high?")
prevdL = input(true, title="show previous day low?")

//previous week
prevWeekHigh = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'W', high[1], lookahead=true)
prevWeekLow = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'W', low[1], lookahead=true)
prevWeekMid = (prevWeekHigh+prevWeekLow)/2
prevWeekMidLow = (prevWeekMid+prevWeekLow)/2
prevWeekMidHigh = (prevWeekHigh+prevWeekMid)/2

//previous day
prevDayHigh = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", high[1], lookahead=true)
prevDayLow = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low[1], lookahead=true)

//previous Week Plots
transparentW = color.new(color.white, 50)
transparent99 = color.new(color.white, 99)
plot(prevwkH and prevWeekHigh ? prevWeekHigh : na, title="Prev Week High", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=1, color=color.white)
plotshape(prevwkH and prevWeekHigh ? prevWeekHigh : na, location=location.absolute, textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="Weekly High",  offset = 30, color=transparent99)

plot(prevwkL and prevWeekLow ? prevWeekLow : na, title="Prev Week Low", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=1, color=color.white)
plotshape(prevwkL and prevWeekLow ? prevWeekLow : na, location=location.absolute, textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="Weekly Low",  offset = 30, color=transparent99)

plot(prevwkM and prevWeekMid ? prevWeekMid : na, title="Prev Week Mid", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=1, color=color.white)
plotshape(prevwkM and prevWeekMid ? prevWeekMid : na, location=location.absolute, textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="Weekly Middle",  offset = 30, color=transparent99)

plot(prevwkMH and prevWeekMidHigh ? prevWeekMidHigh : na, title="Prev Week Middle-High", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=0, color=transparentW)
plotshape(prevwkMH and prevWeekMidHigh ? prevWeekMidHigh : na, location=location.absolute, textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="Weekly Mid-High",  offset = 30, color=transparent99)

plot(prevwkML and prevWeekMidLow ? prevWeekMidLow : na, title="Prev Week Middle-Low", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=0, color=transparentW)
plotshape(prevwkML and prevWeekMidLow ? prevWeekMidLow : na, location=location.absolute, textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="Weekly Mid-Low",  offset = 30, color=transparent99)

//previous day Plots
transparent = color.new(color.white, 60)
plot(prevdH and prevDayHigh ? prevDayHigh : na, title="Prev Day High", style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1, color=transparent)
plotshape(prevdH and prevDayHigh ? prevDayHigh : na, location=location.absolute, textcolor=transparent, show_last=1, text="Yesterday High",  offset = 30, color=transparent99)
plot(prevdL and prevDayLow ? prevDayLow : na, title="Prev Day Low", style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1, color=transparent)
plotshape(prevdL and prevDayLow ? prevDayLow : na, location=location.absolute, textcolor=transparent, show_last=1, text="Yesterday Low",  offset = 30, color=transparent99)


plot(close)`
```

Answer (score -1):

`hline()` can only accept a literal int/float or input int/float. If you don't want to use plots and show all historical levels then you will have to use the line functions to draw your levels.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you, I solved it by adding "trackprice=true, offset=-9999" inside plot command